# A method with return type Set<Set<Integer>> is providing inconsistent output based on input

Tags: java, algorithm, set, combinations

While strengthening my understanding of the Set class, I was given the following prompt: "A combination is a way of selecting a given number of elements from a set of given sizes. As you might already know, there are `n! / (k! * (n-k)!)` ways of choosing `k` elements from an `n`-element set"

```
n - size of the set
k - number of elements to be chosen from the set
```

The output is a "set of combinations, encoded as k-sized Sets of integers containing indices of chosen elements (zero-based)."

```
int: n = 3, k = 2

Set<Set<Integer>>: [[0,1], [1,2], [0,2]]
```

I came to the following approach:

```java
public static Set<Set<Integer>> generateCombinations(int n, int k) {
    Set<Set<Integer>> totalCombinations = new HashSet<>();

    int total = (n == 0 || k == 0 || n < k)
            ? 0
            : (n == k)
                    ? 1
                    : factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));

    while (totalCombinations.size() < total) {
        Set<Integer> combination = new HashSet<>();

        while (combination.size() < k) {
            combination.add((int) (Math.random() * n));
        }
        totalCombinations.add(combination);
    }
    return totalCombinations;
}

public static int factorial(int n) {
    return n * ((n > 1) ? factorial(n - 1) : n);
}
```

Some inputs that work:

```
generateCombinations(3, 2): [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]
generateCombinations(3, 1): [[0], [1], [2]]
generateCombinations(1, 2): []
generateCombinations(0, 6): []
```

Some inputs that don't work:

```
generateCombinations(14, 4): [[2, 9, 10, 12], [3, 5, 12, 13], [4, 10, 11, 12], [6, 8, 12, 13], [1, 2, 4, 8], [0, 5, 6, 7], [0, 3, 7, 10], [1, 2, 7, 12], [2, 5, 8, 9], [1, 2, 9, 13], [1, 4, 8, 13], [1, 7, 8, 13], [0, 7, 10, 12], [3, 4, 11, 12]]
generateCombinations(15, 4): [[4, 9, 10, 13], [0, 1, 4, 5]]
generateCombinations(15, 2): []
generateCombinations(13, 2): [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 7], [3, 4], [3, 5], [1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 6], [1, 8], [1, 10], [0, 12], [1, 11], [1, 12], [2, 12], [4, 10], [6, 9], [7, 8], [3, 12], [4, 12], [7, 10], [8, 10], [7, 11], [9, 10]]
```

I have been debugging like a pest agency and can't figure out what is up with my code. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**Note: the ternary expression to find the total is in place of a try-catch block for division by zero**

Comment: "Debugging like a pest agency"? Try printing the value of `total` for `generateCombinations(15, 2)`. Then learn about integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Try printing the value of total for generateCombinations(15, 2). Then learn about integer overflow. –
> tgdavies

Thank you for the insight, that is what this site is here for. I know about overflow which is why I facepalmed to the roof. For those that do not know, hitting the value of 2^32 with integers will send you into the negatives. While this is not a permanent fix -- BigInteger is preferable for extreme edge cases -- here lies the problem:

```java
public static int factorial(int n)
    return n * ((n > 1) ? factorial(n - 1) : n);
}
```

and here is a simple solution:

```java
public static double factorial(double n)
    return n * ((n > 1) ? factorial(n - 1) : n);
}
```

**Edit for a more detailed solution**

```java
// exact decimal values
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    return (n.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) <= 0)
            ? BigInteger.ONE
            : n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}

// finding the number of combinations given the algorithm
public static long total(int n, int k) {
    if (n == 0 || k == 0 || n < k)
        return 0;
    if (n == k)
        return 1;
    BigInteger factorial = factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(n))
            .divide(factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(k))
                    .multiply(factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(n - k))));
    return factorial.longValue();
}
```

This states that BigInteger `n` will be divided by the product of `factorial(n - 1)` and `factorial(n - k)` where `n` is the number of elements and `k` is the size of each list generated

Comment: Also with `factorial(n) / (factorial(k)` you should consider [Integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: also this problem could be solved without knowing the number of answers, and without depending on random number generation

Comment: Could you guys please provide examples too? Reading it and seeing it are different animals.